# How to read merged cell with xlrd in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlrd

I'm trying to read merged cells from sheet and unfortunately nothing is working for me. I'm in a situation where i want to read **Row merges, column merges or may be combination of both**. Any help will be appreciated.
PS. I already tried **sheets.merged_cells** which returns blank array.

Thank you.

Comment: Please supply a small xls file with merged cells in it, and a small python script that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Docs: http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Sheet.merged_cells

Please ensure that you have read the second "Note" -- if you don't specify `formatting_info=True` in `xlrd.open_workbook()`, you will get an empty list (what you call a "blank array").

Comment: It seems that `formatting_info` flag is not needed (or even supported) anymore, at least with `xlsx` files.

Comment: formatting_info is need for xls only, it does not work on xlsx